# How do I extract indices of non-equivalent entries between two tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor with N predictions of N objects' classes, and I have another tensor with the real N target objects' classes. I would like to pull out the tensor indices where my classifier predictions are wrong.

Consider the two following tensors defined as:

```
import torch
predictions = torch.tensor([ [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [1] ])
target      = torch.tensor([ [0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [1] ])
```

I want to find some function where I can pass these two vectors and have returned a list like `index_diff = [1, 3]`. Does this function exist? My current thoughts are to cast both of these vectors to numpy arrays and then loop through N times and compare each entry at each index, but this seemed a little circuitous to me. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
index_diff = (predictions.flatten() != target.flatten()).nonzero().flatten()
```

should work.

Comment: This did it, thanks! It even works when the tensors are formatted slightly differently, such as: ``predictions = torch.tensor([ [0], [0] ])`` and ``target = torch.tensor([0, 0])``.

Comment: yup, `.flatten()` reshapes a tensor to a 1d tensor. You can play with removing them to see how it behaves.